# Using Octave to solve systems of two non-linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, math-software, octave

How to solve following system of ordinary differential equations using Octave?

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = - [x(t)]^2 -  x(t)y(t)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = - [y(t)]^2 -  x(t)y(t)$$

**Update:** initial conditions: $x(t=0) = x_0, \space y(t=0) = y_0$

Comment: What are the initial conditions? Also, since Octave is the free version of MATLAB, you may get better results including it in google searches also.

Comment: What kind of solution can Octave give you?

Comment: Here is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221534/coupled-nonlinear-ode/221587#221587).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I am counting on analytical solution.. Not sure if I can get it from Octave

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution computed by Maple,

$$ x \left( t \right) = {\frac {x_{{0}}}{y_{{0}}t+x_{{0}}t+1}},y
\left( t \right) = {\frac {y_{{0}}}{y_{{0}}t+x_{{0}}t+1}}.$$

Comment: I just posted the same solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/247849/36034). I don't have the luxury of a computer system, so my brain got a work out.

Comment: @Daryl: Good for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Euler's method, which would use the approximation
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\approx\frac{x(t+\Delta t)-x(t)}{\Delta t}$$
for some "small" $\Delta t$. Then the problem becomes finite difference problem
$$x(t_{n+1})=x(t_{n})+\Delta t\bigl[ - [x(t)]^2 -  x(t)y(t)\bigr]$$
$$y(t_{n+1})=y(t_{n})+\Delta t\bigl[ - [y(t)]^2 -  x(t)y(t)\bigr]$$
where $t_{n}=t_{0}+n\Delta t$.

Of course, the slick way is to change coordinates to
$$u=x+y,\quad\mbox{and}\quad v=x-y$$
so your differential equations become
$$\dot{u}=-u^{2}$$
and
$$\dot{v}=-uv$$
which are quite trivial.