# Is following system of nonlinear ODEs recognized?

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

The following system of ODEs – is it recognized as distinct system, with meaningful background and uses?

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = - [x(t)]^2 -  x(t)y(t)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = - [y(t)]^2 -  x(t)y(t)$$

This is probably not needed, but initial conditions: $x(t=0) = x_0, \space y(t=0) = y_0$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Octave to solve systems of two non-linear ODEs](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245435/using-octave-to-solve-systems-of-two-non-linear-odes)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245435/using-octave-to-solve-systems-of-two-non-linear-odes) is your old question.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: it is not the same question.. The other is – to be strict – not even about finding solution, but about using Octave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a two-dimensional Lotka-Volterra equation. The most general LV-equation  has applications in population dynamics, networks and chemical reactions.

Comment: All summands are negative – is this allowed in L-V equations?

Comment: @Drenet  Yes. In fact it is very common.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recognise the ODE system, but you can obtain a solution analytically.

**Hint**: Let $u=1/x$ and $v=1/y$, as though each is a [Bernoulli differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation). You can then show that, if $x_0\neq0$ and $y_0\neq0$, a solution is given by
$$x(t)=\frac{x_0}{1+\left(x_0+y_0\right)t},\\
y(t)=\frac{y_0}{1+\left(x_0+y_0\right)t}.$$

Comment: You don't need the conditions $x_0 \ne 0$ and $y_0 \ne 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Perhaps, but for the derivation I used, this condition is required.

Comment: Here's a useful principle: once the solution has been found, it doesn't really matter how you found it.  To check that it is a solution, just plug it in to the differential equation.  If it works, it works.

Comment: How to go from your solution, to the following? http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/500/what-is-probability-of-3-possible-products-between-two-chemical-species

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it has a name, but you might notice that trajectories are rays from the origin (apart from the fixed points along $x+y=0$).