# differential system

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

We consider the differential system
$$
\begin{cases}
& y'(t)=a y(t)^3 + b z(t)\\
& z'(t)=c z(t)^5 - b y(t)
\end{cases}
$$
with $t>0$

$y(0)=y_0, z(0)=z_0,\quad a<0,\quad c<0,\quad b\in \mathbb{R}$

the question is to prouve that this system admits a unique solution on $[0,+\infty[$?

Comment: I think you can get an approximate solution using power series techniques.

Comment: Check this [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245435/using-octave-to-solve-systems-of-two-non-linear-odes).

Comment: I think that we must use the Cauchy Lipschitz Theorem. But how we can use it?

Comment: @wiwi Please do not deface your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By standard ODE theorems, we know that if a solution doesn't exist, it will only not exist because the solution "blows up," that is, if there exists a $T>0$ such that $x(t)$ or $y(t)$ is unbounded as $t \to T^-$.

Multiply the first equation by $y(t)$, and the second solution by $z(t)$, and then add them together, you obtain
$$ \frac12 \frac d{dt}((y(t))^2 + (z(t))^2) = a (y(t))^4 + c(z(t))^6 .$$
Since $a$ and $c$ are negative, it follows that $(y(t))^2 + (z(t))^2$ is bounded.  Hence a blow up can never happen.